# Why can't we walk full clockwise in shiva temple?

Tags: shiva, practice, temple

While on Shiva Temple, we does not walk full clockwise around the temple, why? What is the reason behind it?

Comment: I live in Bhubaneshwar ---which has a large number of Shiva Temples --the biggest of which is the Lingaraj Temple. I have not come across such restrictions. Probably these restrictions depend on local beliefs .

Comment: Related question [Does pradakshina direction differ with each stage of life (ashrama)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3096/5212)

Comment: Same question here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14849/why-dont-we-do-complete-pradaxina-circumambulation-of-shivalingam/15361#15361

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I have heard something like this :-

There is always an outlet (opening for letting out the "Theerth") on one side of the platform or room where the deity is embarked.

Have you ever noticed that it points to the North (If located in India) ? 
That means logically it is an opening or passage to Mount Kailas (in the northest part of India).

It is believed that "BhoothGana" come and go out frequently to visit the Lord, using this passage. So it is supposed that we block their path when we walk in a full circle.

This is why we just turn back when we reach this outlet.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Answer (score 2):

**While on Shiva Temple, we does not walk full clockwise around the temple, why? What is the reason behind it**?

The Gandharva-Tantra has instructions of walking around Shiva (Shiva-Pradakshina).Lord Shiva says:

> dakshinAd vayavim gatvA tasmAd vyAvritya dakshinam/gatvA yo'sau namaskarah so'rdhochandro mama priyah//(Ahnik-kritya, Shyamacharan Kaviratna Vidyavaridhi, Vol.1,page 19).
>
> Meaning : My favourite is that prostration which is done with walking from the south by going to the 'vayu-kone' and again walking back to south **along a** half-moon (**half-circular**) **path**.

**The pinaka or 'pranala' that carries 'Tirtha' is on the northern side. One must not cross that**. The Devi-Purana says

> savyam vrajet tato'savyam pranAlam naiva langhyaet (Ibid.page 19).

The Devi-Purana also advises to do such 'Pradakshina' **thrice** with a mind focused on Rudra/Shiva, doing which ine is freed from workdliness and is not born again:

> ekibhutamanA rudre yah kuryAt trih pradakshinam/chhinnas tena bhava-granthir na tasya punar udbhavah//(Ibid.mpage 19).