# Why don't we do complete 'Pradaxina' (Circumambulation) of Shivalingam?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

Why don't we do complete `Pradaxina` of lord Shiva - `Shivalingam`?

In a Shiva temple from a panditjee over there I've heard that we can't do complete `Pradaxina` of `Shivalingam` because he is **`Ardhanaareshvar`**. Later I came to know about the story of how lord Shiva known as `Ardhanaareshvar`, but my question remains there only.

I've read many blogs but didn't get answer about this.

Comment: As we can't cross from the top of 'Abhishek' water small canel as it's a pavitra. This would be the main reason behind it. We can't cross from top of any pavitra things.

Comment: What to do if I have done 6-7 parikrama of shivling in childhood even after being told not to... How to repent to shiv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Shastras prescribe  only a **half pradkashina** for Shiva.That is why we do not complete the pradakshina.

For the [Pancha Devata Deities](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15144/do-any-deities-other-than-the-pancha-mahadevatas-have-swayambhu-representation) the rules(for pradakshina ) are as follows:

> Eka Chandaya Raveh Sapta Tirstra Karya Vinayake||
>
> Hareschatarstrah Kartabyah **Shivasya ardha Pradkshina**||
>
> (For Durga(Chandi) (one should do) 1 pradkshina,for Surya(Ravi)
>   7,for Ganesha(Vinayaka) 3,for Vishnu(Hari) 4 & **for Shiva only 1/2**.

[image]

[image]

Refer to image above.The pradakshina should not go beyond the "Gomukhi".As the holy water constantly drips and gets collected there(this is the most rational reason i can think of).

By half pradakshina is meant a "SomaSutra Pradakshina" as stated in the next Sloka:

> Shivam PradaksiniKurvan **Somasutram na Langhayeth**,Iti Vachanantaraat.
>
> (While doing Shiva Pradakshina the order(of Shastras) is that one
>   **should not break the Somasutra**).

By Somasutra is meant the Half Moon like curve that is traced out in the process.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for it! Didn't even aware about that.. but what is the reason behind that? There must be some story or legend behind that.. why only half a pradaxina? can you provide information about that?

Comment: @Paritosh I have added a bit more information in my answer for better clarification.

Comment: I guess that's what @Abjo was pointing to. Can you provide reference from where you've got the 2nd shloka - 'Somasutram na Langhayeth'? I need it before I mark this one as answer - **[quotations of scripture references?](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-we-enforce-quotations-of-scripture-references)**, http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/242/lets-not-upvote-answers-which-do-not-have-correct-source-as-reference

Comment: That sloka is from a Achara Samhita book.