# Is Banlinga/Naramadeshwar Linga proscribed to keep at home? Why?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

Is Banlinga/Naramadeshwar proscribed to keep at home? Why? Any story behind them?

Comment: Yes banalinga can be kept at home.Here are the reasons-There r 2 types of prana paratishta in idols 1)Achala & 2)Chala.Achala is the one where avahanam.visarjanam r not needed.This type is recommended for Temples.Here God stays all the time.In homes chala pratishta is recommended.In this case both avahanam and visarjanam is required.Now since Banalingas r swaymabhu avahana.visarjana r not needed in them ,so can be safely kept and worshiped in homes.U can see this Q-http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15434/do-scriptures-confirm-about-the-swayambhu-nature-of-shalagramas-and-banalingas