# is the tradition of invoking Ganesa at the beginning of pujas and undertakings in real life known in North India also?

Tags: ganesha

sects that reject Siva and deities related to him are excluded of course.  The serial on Ganesa running right now says Siva's first attempt to fight the tripurasuras failed because he didn't invoke Ganesa (his own son !!) first.

http://pulivahanan.wikifoundry.com/page/What+is+the+significance+of+the+pillaiyar+suzhi%3F

"It is a faith amongst practicing hindus that before commencing any work Lord Ganesha’s blessing is sought, the work undertaken will be accomplished without any obstacles, therefore all Hindus invoke him with the firm belief that he will take care of every obstacle that they come across"

Comment: The story of Tripurasara where Ganesha is worshipped is present in Shiva Purana. I think Skanda Purana also mentions it.

Comment: Yes, he is. for a matter of fact all North indian homes have Lord ganesha's photo kept above the front door/entrance of house, he is worshipped as supari like how shaligram is used for Vishnu.

Comment: Yes very much so.. many scriptures say that Lord Ganesha should be worshipped first in any ritual.. it is also said if one does not do so then his subsequent worship does not bear fruits because that deity rejects his worship then..

Comment: if you post the scripture that says he should be worshiped first, I'll accept the answer. @rickross

Comment: Just like Lord Vishnu has the swayambhu sila called Shaligrama, every other Pancha Devatas also each have their respective such silas.. For Lord Ganesha it's called the Sonebhadra sila due to the fact that it's found in that river, see this post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15144/do-any-deities-other-than-the-pancha-mahadevatas-have-swayambhu-representation @AnubhavJha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.. because that Lord Ganesha has to be worshipped first in any rituals is a scriptural injunction and so it's universally followed by every Hindus irrespective of regions.

For example from [Linga Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/lingapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=19), we find:

> As the Bala Ganapati prostrated before his parents Shiva and Parvati,
>   the latter posted kisses on the son’s head and prescribed the do’s and
>   don’ts such as to create hidrances in the execution of Yagnas without
>   dakshinas, destroy serial Daityas and protect Brahma Vaadi Dwijas and
>   Siddhas; as also to those who perform Vedaadhyana, Adhyaapana and
>   Vkyakhyaana improperly; at the same time Ganesha shoud reward those
>   who perform worship daily, bestow prosperity to the virtuous and
>   protect the youth and elderly. By so doing  Vighna Nayaka would be the
>   most sought after in Tri Lokas, told Ganesha by the parents. **Shiva
>   emphasised to Ganesha that any Puja to him, Vishnu or Brahma or other
>   Devatas or Devis must be preceded by worhip to Ganesha first not only
>   to assure success of the main Puja but also supplement the fulfillment
>   of the desires for which the main puja was performed. The Prathama
>   Puja to Ganesha should be also done with
>   Dhyana-Avahana-Pushpa-Gandha-Dhupa-Deepa-Naivedyas just as the Main
>   Devata of the Puja was to be performed. This is relevant to all Varnas
>   of Brahmana-Kshatriya-Vaishya and others too. Thus any worship, or
>   Vrata, or Sacred and Religious Deed like Yagnas, Daanaas, Vivaahas,
>   Upanayanas, Vidyaarambhas, house constructions, or for that matter any
>   and every task seeking propitiousness shoud start with Ganesha Puja**
>   in Hindu Dharma with the invocation to Vighneswara thus: ‘Shuklaambara
>   dharam Vishnum Shashi Varnam Chaturbhujam Prasanna Vadanam Dhyaayet
>   Sarva Vighnopashaantaye’!

Similarly the [Varaha Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=11) states:

> Lord Siva got annoyed by the instant reaction of Devi Parvati, became
>   jealous of the Super Boy and infact got angry and cursed him saying
>   that he would possess an elephant face, disproportionate belly and
>   serpented Yagnopaveeth (Holy Thread).Siva was still angry and from His
>   body hair roots kept on multiplying innumerable Vinayaks resembling
>   the original and Lord Brahma flew over the Sky and **as Akashvani ( a
>   loud announcement from the Sky) declared that Devas should be grateful
>   to Lord Siva to have provided the solution to the problem posed by
>   them and that the various forms of Vinayak which got materialised
>   would indeed ensure that as and when Devas ( and human beings)
>   initiated a task they should invoke the blessings of Vinayak
>   foremost.** As the announcement from Brahma was heard, Siva was by
>   then cooled down and addressed Vinayaka endearingly;
>
> Ganesh Puja:
>
> Vinayako Vighnakaro Gajasyo Ganesha naamaacha Bhavasya Putrah,
>   Yethecha Sarvam thava yanthu Bhruthya Vinayakayaah Kruura drishtah
>   Prachandah-Vucchushma daanaadi vuvruddhva dehaha Karyeshu siddhim
>   prati paadayanthah, Bhavaamsva Deveshu thadha makeshu kaaryashu
>   chanteshu Mahanubhavat-Agreshu Pujam Labhatenyatha cha
>   Vinashayishyastatha kaarya siddhim
>
> Hey Putra! Vinayaka, Vighnakara, Gajavadana, Ganesha, Shankara Putra;
>   all these cruel-eyed, harsh and angry Vinayaks will be your servants;
>   those who are desirous of giving well earned materials as daanas or
>   alms be provided with Siddhis or boons. **At Yajnas or various
>   Propitious Tasks, all the devotees shall provide you the highest
>   veneration, lest their tasks or worships be discounted.**

Some more verses from the Katyayana Smriti's first chapter:

> Gouri, Padma, S'achi, Medha, Savitri, Vijaya, Java, Devasena, Svadha,
>   Svaha, Dhriti, Pushti, Tushti with Atmadevata, these Matris are the
>   mothers of the Lokas. **For performing a Vriddhi-rite (on the occasion
>   of a marriage, etc.,) these fourteen, added by Ganesha,. should be
>   adored, (12**)
>
> **In all religious rites, the Matris with the leader ,of the Ganas (Ganes'a) should be adored with care. They, being adored, make  [the
>   performer] worthy of adoration. (13)**

So, Vedic rituals must begin with the adoration of Ganesha and that of the Matrikas. And every Hindus more or less follow these instructions be it in North or South or wherever.

(NOTE- The Katyayana Smriti is one among the 18 major Smritis of Hinduism.)

Comment: "Yes.. because that Lord Ganesha has to be worshipped first in any rituals is a scriptural injunction and so it's universally followed by every Hindus irrespective of regions."  @rickross except Iyengars of course !!  Large numbers of them now observe vinayaka chaturthi - but diehards push the Vishvaksena to take the place of Vinayaka

Comment: Everyone should..-now if some people don't do that, then it's their fault.. they are not above scriptures.. @SK

Comment: @SK leave North Indians and vaishnavas you should worry about white malecchas claiming Lord ganesha to be a later interpolated diety.

Comment: this is slimy.  are you pushing your views as the views of whites?

Comment: @SK no, I'm not. Ganesha is well respected among vaishnavas, don't generalize vaishnavas.

Comment: @Rickross Vaishnavas don't because their scriptures say something about Vishwaksena as the lord of obstacles. So, they are following those scriptures. It is not their fault. They are following scriptures. Don't post such comments that they are not following scriptures and not above scriptures.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I am not bothered about what some people do or do not do.. coz every Hindus i have seen in eastern and northern India worship Lord Ganesha before every rituals.. coz that's the rule.. as u can see the Smritis also say the same.. so it's part of Vedic Dharma.. coz the Smritis elaborate the Vedic Dharma..also which comment of mine are u talking about something that i have said in the answer or?