# What are symbols for worshipping Goddess Sarasvati, Goddess Lakshmi and Lord Brahma of the trinity pantheon?

Tags: vishnu, brahma, shiva-lingam, lakshmi, saraswati

It is often said that when there was a feud/ struggle for Swarga between deisms (led by Lord Indra) and devils(led by Jalandhar) the deisms were unable to assassinate Jalandhar due to piousness of her wife Tulsi. Deisms went to Lord Shri Vishnu for help. Lord Shree Vishnu took a form similar to Jalandhar and went to Tulsi who was devout only to her husband and considering Lord Vishnu to be her husband spend some time with her. Meanwhile Jalandhar was slain in war, when Tulsi came to know of the fact she cursed Lord Shree Vishnu to stay on earth as Shaaligram stone (found in river Gandaki, Nepal). Due to her curse Tulsi too was transformed into a plant (Raama Tulsi).

Legend also has it that Baanasur whoose 998 hands out of his preexisting thousand hands were cut by shree Krishna so he can not stop the waters of Narmada river. Lord Shiva gave the boon to Baanasur (his devotee) that he will reside in all the lings (probably made by Baanasur) found in Narmada river-bed and Such lings won't need awaahan of Lord Shiva.

My question is If by virtue of these Puraanic events and others Lord Vishnu, Lord Shiva, Lord Ganpati, Lord Surya and Goddess Paarvati are said to reside in Shaaligram Shila, Baanling, Sonbhadra Shila, Sphatik and Swarnamukhi Shila respectively; Are there similar symbols present in Hinduism to worship Goddess Saraswati, Goddess Lakshmi and Creator Lord Brahma ? Please enlighten ?

Comment: Hello! I have asked the same question here (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15144/4732) .. apparently there are no such Swayambhu silas for other deities.