# Are there devotional objects for worship of Lord Vishnu (comparable to the shivling used for worshipping Lord Shiva)?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, worship, puja, shiva-lingam

For Lord Shiva, there are shivlings/lingam that people use for devotional worship.

Are there any comparable devotional objects that many people use to worship Lord Vishnu, or objects that represent Lord Vishnu (other than, for example, a murti that is shaped in his image)?

*(Apologies if my question seems basic; there is much for me to learn but I would be grateful for any information or suggestions for further reading. I did search the site for an answer before posting this question.)*

Comment: Only Shiva is worshipped in an abstract form like Shiva Lingam. All other deities are invoked/worshipped in an image or idol. Also see this --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15144/4732

Comment: Apart from idols there are also respective Yantras for each deity .. here is Vishnu Yantra in which he can be worshipped too -- https://www.pandit.com/shop/shri-vishnu-yantra/

Comment: @Rickross Thank you - this is really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lord Vishnu is worshipped as [Shaligrama Shila](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaligram).

**Sri Shiva Maha Purana 2.5:5:41.:**

> *49. As a result of your (Tulsi's) curse, **Hari shall assume the form of a rock on the banks of the river Gaṇḍakī and shall preside on the same in Bharata.***
>
> *50. Crores of terrible sharp-toothed germs shall penetrate and erode the rock and carve rings on it.*
>
> *51. Those pieces shall be known as **Śālagrāma rocks** and will be meritorious. Differentiated by the rings they shall be known as Lakṣmīnārāyaṇa etc.*
>
> *52. **O Viṣṇu, Śālagrāma stone shall signify your contact with Tulasī. Similar in appearance they shall increase merit.***

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Wow, I had seen discussions about Shaligram but had no idea about their significance. Thank you for sharing this and for linking further reading, and for the reference to the relevant section in the Sri Shiva Maha Purana -- much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. ..