# Can I pour water on the shivling for abhishek as many times as I want?

Tags: shiva, rituals, shiva-lingam, puja

I go to a temple where there is a shivling set on some soil at the base of a tree. So all the water poured goes in the root, and I feel good about giving the tree so much Shiva Nirmalaya to drink. Whenever I go to the temple, I try to pour water from a jug (lota) as many times as I can. Note that the water doesn't fall on the floor or anything, it goes into the soil and feeds the tree the Shiva Nirmalaya. However, today the priest stopped me and started to scold me saying (Hindi)

> "Ye puja kar rahe ho ya mazak kar rahe ho. Ye tumhara paanchwa lota hai"

(English Translation)

> "Is this puja (worship) or a joke? This is your fifth jug (lota)."

So I was wondering if there is such a thing as overoffering water to the shivling? Can I offer water as many times as I want to the shivling or is there a limit of one or three or the number of letters in the panchakshari mantra or something like that?

EDIT : I want to know the scriptural injunctions regarding amount to be offered to the shivling. Just for the sake of more information, the temple I go to has a pipeline supply so there is no question of running out of water. I do admit that noone else pours as much water as me (11 lotas or mini-jugs). Also, there are many shivlings in the temple and at each one, multiple people can pour water at the same time, so I am not holding up the crowd or anything.

EDIT 2 : Some prescribed quantities are mentioned in this answer - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17187/16709 - but it is also mentioned that Shukracharya did Abhishek "a thousand times".

Comment: @TigerShroff - if you dissolve yourself in Shiva, with such peak devotion, you can pour water how much ever you want, the water will just keep coming and will have no end and wont be wasted! But until we reach that stage of peak devotion, we have to abide by limitations and regulations!

Comment: @Sarvabhouma you mention about 100 or 200 times. In 'Rudrabhishek', where there is continuous pouring of water, what will you call it? Wastage?? Further, the OP mentioned that water is going into tree roots. So where is wastage?

Comment: @Vineet I have to agree with the priest there. Even me and you are not above that priest in terms of knowledge. If someone has a hundred tankers of water and pours everything on Shiva lingam, that will not be a good way to use water. Obviously, that person is doing out of devotion and feels good. But what is the outcome? And  @@Tiger shroff, Rudrabhishek is different and what normal people do is different. Only the priest has a the right to do abhishek and there are certain rules to be followed while doing. It is not like pouring whatever, whenever we want. We should also see rationality.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I did not mention to dishonour the priest there. We are discussing OP's Q -- "is there a limit of one or three or the number of letters in the panchakshari mantra or something like that?". Also, "hundred tankers" argument is just an exaggeration. You are asking "what is the outcome?". With this "outcome" logic, all the pooja, bhakti etc. would become worthless...

Comment: @Vineet There is nothing here to feel sorry or anything. I didn't say anything wrong. The priest is also asking to stop pouring many times. We should not waste valuable resources in the name of devotion. That can be used many ways feeding poor. Regarding rules, re read my comment. There are certain rules when to worship, how to worship and do sevas like abhishek. See complete answer which says there are rules to touch and serve shiva lingam. (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11675/5212)

Comment: What is the problem if u do it? I mean are there more people waiting behind u for u to complete? You could hv also asked the priest himself politely to explain why it is a wrong thing to do. @Tiger Next time whn u go there ask him and may be u can post an answer then with Purohitji's words as the source :)

Comment: @Rickross - No there was noone waiting for me, I wasn't blocking the line or anything. Plus it is an open space around the tree, multiple people can (and do) pour water (and milk) together on the shivling. There are also multiple shivlings in the temple so people can pour water on other shivlings if one is too crowded.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, I agree that Rudrabhishek performed by the priests is much more effective. For eg. I haven't memorized the Rudrapatha which they chant during it, and their rhythms and pitches are probably much more accurate. But do you mean to say that any water or milk or honey etc. we pour on the shivling while chanting say, om namah shivaya is wasted? Is it not an authentic process of devotional service to Lord Shiva? Also, the temple I go to has a pipeline water supply and I use maybe 11 jugs (lotas) in total, but noone else uses as much as me so there is no question of running out.

Comment: BTW, which is this place with many shiva lingas in open space, with a priest? Never heard of like this. Just curious..

Comment: Well, by open space I meant 'spread openly' inside the temple itself. It is a temple in Lucknow. Ask for a Hanuman Mandir near Burlington Chauraha. It has a total of 5 shivlings, three of them are very small though (black stone). Two are silver coloured metal, not sure what the metal is though.

Comment: pl mention @username else the concerned user won't get notified. 'silver coloured metal' may be 'Parad Shivling'. My guess.

Comment: @TigerShroff Check [**this video**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=pouring+water+on+shivling&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN819IN819&oq=water+pouring+on+shi&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l4.11871j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=1)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Can you tell me which section of the video I should watch which is relevant to my answer?

Comment: @Tiger The link should play exactly what you should watch. Note that this video Does not have complete answer to your question.